# Regex expression for matching $(..)

Tags: c++, regex

Suppose I have a string that looks like this

```
std::string str = "I have $(xb) books and $(cs) pens";
```

What is the easiest way to extract `xb` and `cs` (extract characters surounded by `$()` ) from the statement ?
Is it possible to do some regex magic that would return a vector that contains `xb` and `cs` ?

I am trying something like this

```
regex rgx("$\\(*\\)");//$(*)

smatch result;
regex_search(var, result, rgx);

for(size_t i=0; i<result.size(); ++i){
cout << result[i] << endl;
}
```

However I am not getting any success . What I would like is `xb` and `cs` in a vector. I tried coming up with an expression but i cant figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` has a special meaning and `*` applies to the opening brace in your regex.

You could use a capturing group and match starting at the char after the opening brace that's not a closing brace in the brackets, i.e. use the regex `\$\(([^)]*)\)`:

```
std::string str = "I have $(xb) books and $(cs) pens";
std::regex rgx("\\$\\(([^)]*)\\)");

for (auto pos = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), rgx), end = std::sregex_iterator();
    pos != end; ++pos) {
    const std::smatch& match = *pos;
    std::cout << match[1] << std::endl;
}
```